# Observing Content Changes in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, dom-events

I'm trying to implement a new Polymer custom element.  However, I would like to fire a custom event when the content of the element changes.  My code thus far is as follows:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../lib/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="dnd-dropdown" attributes="field">
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dnd-dropdown.css">
        <div id="c">
            <div class="dndValue"><content></content></div>
            <div class="dndTitle">{{field}}</div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            field: "...",

            ready: function () {
                this.onMutation(this, this.contentChanged);
            },

            contentChanged: function (e) {
                console.log("contentChanged event fired");
                console.log("event = %o", e);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

My theory on this was that the onMutation would fire whenever the dndValue node changes (i.e. the content of the element changes) and that would print the two console messages.  However when I change the element in F12 Developer Tools in Chrome, nothing happens.

What is the best way of observing content changes in Polymer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bumped into the solution after just about every iteration of possibilities, so this is an empirical "it works" answer rather than a definitive "this is the best way to do it" kind of answer.

The short version: Use a custom [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver).

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
        ready: function () {
            var that = this, observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                console.debug("Firing textChanged event on field ", that.field, " new value ", mutations[0].target.textContent);
                this.fire("textChanged", { field: this.field, value: mutations[0].target.textContent });
            }).observe(this, { childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true });
        },
```

When this is run from Internet Explorer (Tech Preview), a total of 3 childList mutations are observed.  When run from Chrome (which has good support for custom elements), only one characterData mutation is observed.  As a result, I fire the new event for just the first event which always seems to catch the "right thing".  Given the differing implementations, this is probably a little brittle.

I do not know how this works with Firefox or Opera.  Caniuse.com says there is support for MutationObserver in everything but Opera Mini so I can surmise that it won't work in Opera Mini.

Answer (score 2):

An updated approach for Polymer 1.7:

With the following template

```
<template>
  <content id="myContent"></content>
</template>
```

You can observe node changes with

```
attached: function() {
  Polymer.dom(this.$.myContent).observeNodes(this._nodesChanged);
},

_nodesChanged: function() {
  var elements = this.$.myContent.getElements();

  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    $(elements[i]).on("change", function(){
      this.doStuffWithChangedNodes();
    }.bind(this));
  }

  this.doStuffWithChangedNodes();
},

doStuffWithChangedNodes: function() {
  var elements = this.$.myContent.getElements();

  // you can loop and work with each element
  ...
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to make this answer independent of jQuery :)

Comment: Upvoted because Polymer documentation recommends this approach over the use of a Mutation Observer. FYI, there's no jQuery in this post.